# I would like to reproduce this graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to reproduce this figure. Where this case is a heptagon, and the center line until the vertex is a measure between [0-1]. The colored lines would be the result found by an algorithm through each vertex.

Any idea to implement this in matplot polygon? Using polar coordinate? What kind of graph is this?

[image]

edit:

Sorry for the form of the question. Would like to know what kind of graphic would be this, and some matplot would support this.

The user Andy answered me, and my doubt is over.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [radar chart](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html). Matplotlib supports this out of the box and provides very nice samples on how to produce these charts.

Comment: Thank you, it was just what I wanted. I did not know what type of graphic it was.

Sorry for the newby question-